# Menu de Formulário

Tags: jquery, html5, css3

[image: Tela do sistema]

Gostaria que o menu ao lado ficasse selecionado de acordo com a página.O Home está selecionado porque está com a classe "active". Gostaria que fosse selecionado automaticamente ao clicar. Já tentei de todas as formas com CSS e Jquery mas não funciona. Acredito que seja porque os menus estão configurados com rotas, aí a página é recarregada e não mantém o menu ativo.

MENU

```
<div class="navi">
    <ul>
        @can('publica',Auth::user())
           <li class="active"><a href="{{route('home')}}"><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i>HOME</a></li>
        @endcan
        @can('adm',Auth::user())
           <li><a href="{{route('curso_novo')}}"><i class="fa fa-graduation-cap" aria-hidden="true"></i>NOVO CURSO</a></li>
        @endcan
        @can('adm',Auth::user())
           <li><a href="{{route('aluno_cadastrar')}}"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>NOVO ALUNO</a></li>
        @endcan
        @can('publica',Auth::user())
           <li><a href="{{route('aluno_buscar')}}"><i class="fa fa-search-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i>BUSCAR ALUNO</a></li>
        @endcan
           <li><a href="{{route('sair')}}"><i class="fa fa-sign-out" aria-hidden="true"></i>SAIR</a></li>
     </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: Não sei se pode te ajudar, mas tente setar a Classe quando a página é carregada, e não quando o link é clicado. Quando vc Clica a pagina atualiza e vc perde a referencia. Já quando a página é carregada ele lé o dom e coloca o Active onde precisar. Outra opção é usar `localStorage` de uma pesquisada